# Find the volume and total surface area of the solid formed

Tags: integration, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems, plane-geometry, solid-geometry

> Let the planes be defined by $$|x|+|y|+|z|=1$$

Find the volume of the solid enclosed and the total surface area of the solid thus generated.

---

I am not able visualise the solid. What will it be$?$ I can get the equations of all the planes that it will generate under the given condition, but I am not able to determine the solid and then how to find the volume and it's surface area. Also, I am unsure about using integration here$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could try sketching what $|x| + |y| = 1$ looks like in $\Bbb R^2$. You may find this helps you understand the three-dimensional case better!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I know what that looks like...it is a square of area 2 square units...but the problem in 3D is that it is too difficult

Comment: Fixing the sign of each variable puts you in one of $8$ octants. For example, if $x,y,z>0$, then you're bounded on three sides by the planes $x=0,y=0,z=0$ and on another by $z=1-y-x$. What happens in the other octants?

Comment: OK. Note that in 3D, if you only consider the plane where $z = 0$, the shape of the cross-section of the solid in that plane is exactly the shape of $|x| + |y| = 1$. But that's also what the shape will be in the plane where $x = 0$, and also in the plane where $y = 0$. This gives us a sort of "skeleton" of the solid.

Moreover, if you think about "sliding" a plane $z = t$ by varying the value of $t$, the cross-section will look like $|x| + |y|  = 1 - |t|$ at time $t$. What does that look like? Does that help you see what the whole solid looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the equation, you can find the corners of your solid to be $(\pm 1, 0, 0)$, $(0, \pm 1, 0)$, $(0, 0, \pm 1)$. Since the equation is linear, you can imagine your solid as the interior of planes connecting these six corners. Using a bit of imagination, it becomes clear that the solid in question is an octahedron with edge length $\sqrt{2}$. The area is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\cdot(\sqrt{2})^2\cdot8=4 \sqrt{3}$ ($8$ equilateral triangles).

As for the volume, you can find the volume in a single quadrant and multiply by $8$. Volume in a quadrant: $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{2} x^2 dx = \frac{1}{6}$. Total volume: $\frac{1}{6} \cdot 8 = \frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate the integration part more? Like why to integrate this function and won't it find the area instead of volume??

Comment: Consider the quadrant $(+, +, +)$. Then, $x+y+z = 1$. Imagine slicing the volume into planes parallel to the $x-y$ planes. Each plane is a triangle with area $\frac{1}{2} x^2$ (since the equation is symmetric in $x$ and $y$) integrated over the range $x \in [0, 1]$ (since $x$, $y$, and $z$ have to sum to 1).

Comment: Thanks i understood.. though it was a bit challenging

Comment: @user170231 right sorry, the corners are $(\pm 1, 0, 0)$, $(0, \pm 1, 0)$, $(0, 0, \pm 1)$. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $|x| = \alpha x, |y| = \beta y, |z| = \gamma z$, and for the volume consider the integral  $$\alpha \beta \int_0^{\alpha} \int_0^{\frac{(1-\alpha x)}{\beta}}(1- \alpha x - \beta y) dy dx$$ which represents the volume in one octant, where the $\alpha \beta$ term controls the orientation of the definite integrals. This evaluates to $1/6$ irrespective
of the differing values $\alpha, \beta$ for an octant, so $ V=8 \cdot (1/6) = 4/3 $.

For the surface area consider  $$\alpha \beta \int_0^{\alpha} \int_0^{\frac{(1-\alpha x)}{\beta}} \sqrt{1+\frac{\alpha^2}{\gamma^2}+\frac{\beta^2}{\gamma^2}}dy dx$$
$$=\alpha \beta \int_0^{\alpha} \int_0^{\frac{(1-\alpha x)}{\beta}} \sqrt{3}dy dx$$
which comes from the usual surface area integal with $z=\frac{1-\alpha x - \beta y}{\gamma}$. This evaluates to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} $ for every octant, giving $SA = 4\sqrt{3}$.